# One Way Functions with Non-Uniform Inputs

Tags: reference-request, one-way-function

It is well-known that a One-Way Function is hard to invert on uniformly random inputs. As per [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)

> for [sic] all randomized algorithms $F$, all positive integers $c$ and all sufficiently large $n = \mathsf{length}(x)$, $$\Pr[f(F(f(x))) = f(x)]\leq\mathsf{negl}(n)$$ where the probability is over the choice of $x$ from the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}^n$ and the randomness of $F$.

Some basic facts about what happens in the case of non-uniform inputs can be easily ascertained: given, for instance, a *pseudorandom* distribution as input, the function is also hard to invert lest the existence of a distinguisher for the input distribution. It should be similarly easy to prove the hardness of inverting given an input distribution with a non-negligible amount of min-entropy.

What is the state-of-the-art on invertibility guarantees with non-uniform input distributions?

Comment: "It should be similarly easy to prove the hardness of inverting given an input distribution with a non-negligible amount of min-entropy." that's not true. Let $f  : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a OWF. Define $g : \{0,1\}^{2n} \to \{0,1\}^n$ as $g(x\Vert y) := \begin{cases}y&\text{if } x=0^n\\f(y)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. This remains one-way, with a uniform input distribution, but is trivial to invert relative to the distribution with $x=0^n$ and $y$ uniform.